# What is opposite of forceActiveFocus?

Tags: qml

I have these QML lines:

```
Item {
    id:container
    Rectangle {
        id:rec1
        width:20; height:20; x:20; y:20
        color:"blue"
        MouseArea {
            onClicked:rec1.forceActiveFocus();
        }
        //bla bla
    }

    Rectangle {
        id:rec2
        width:20; height:20; x:200; y:200
        color:"red"
        MouseArea {
            onClicked:rec2.forceActiveFocus();
        }
        //bla bla
    }
}
```

When i click one of the rectangle it gains focus and other lose focus.
This is what i want, ok, but i want one rectangle lose focus when i click white space, out of rectangles and in Item, item with id:container?

What should i do into where?

Answer (score 4):

The opposite of focus is focussing something else.
If you want no rectangle to have any focus just call

```
container.forceActiveFocus()
```

Sample solution

```
Rectangle {
    id: container
    width: 240
    height: 240
    color: activeFocus ? "black" : "white"

    MouseArea {
        z: 1
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: container.forceActiveFocus();
    }

    Rectangle {
        id:rec1
        width:20; height:20; x:20; y:20
        z: 2
        color: activeFocus ? "blue" : "lightblue"
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:rec1.forceActiveFocus();
        }
        //bla bla
    }

    Rectangle {
        id:rec2
        width:20; height:20; x:200; y:200
        color: activeFocus ? "red" : "lightsalmon"
        z: 2
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked:rec2.forceActiveFocus();
        }

        //bla bla
    }

}
```

Comment: hi, where should i call forceActiveFocus in parent(encapsulating) item? thanks for reply

Comment: You need another MouseArea, use order or z values to have the children on top of the parent's MouseArea

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're dealing with more complicate layers using FocusScope's, you could just set focus to false:

```
rec1.focus = false;
```